# Applying same symbology to different DEMs?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, dem, attribute-joins, arcscene

I am using ArcScene and ran into this problem where I downloaded a couple of neighboring/bordering DEMs(in BIL format), imported them into the scene (as separate entities) and applied Base Heights so it would display in 3D.

The problem is that the DEMs have slightly different shading so they do not join properly (The color/shading does not match up, but the physical height does).

How do I display them all in the same shade/color/symbology?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

What you could is to create a Mosaic Dataset. Here the singles tiles are converted into one large tile which shows continous displaying.
Here is the reference for the tool on the ESRI website:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-mosaic-dataset.htm

I can't give you any screenshots because ArcGIS is not available to me right now, but what causes often trouble is the selection of the pixel_type. From your screenshot you need to choose 16_BIT_UNSIGNED.